# Limit aws to just s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Is there a way to disable access to all aws services, but s3? I have an account that will only use s3 and I am worried about unexpected charges from running ec2.

Alternatively, is there a way to create a api keys for s3 access only?

Comment: You could easily create an IAM user and allow (maybe) full permissions to S3 and all other services just read only access. In that way even using api keys, he can only use s3 and cant create any other resources in any other services.

Comment: I think this is helpful, thank you. You could provide this as an answer so that other people will find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily create an IAM user and allow (maybe) full permissions to S3 and all other services just read only access. In that way even using api keys, he can only use s3 and cant create any other resources in any other services.